# How do I setup Node.js server to use index.php instead of default index.html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, express, puppeteer

I have a working index.html file.

The index.html is by default the main page in the public directory.

Using a working server.js below, I can generate pdf in the browser:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
//var exec = require("child_process").exec;

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'public')));

app.get('/pdf', async (req, res) => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
// go to page
await page.goto("http://6f8fe372710a.ngrok.io/lesson.php", {
  waitUntil: "networkidle2"
});

// Navigate to a specific div on the website
const dom = await page.$eval('#todo', (el) => {
   return el.innerHTML 
 }) // Get DOM innerHTML

 // inject jQuery


 await page.setContent(dom); 

 
await page.setViewport({ width: 1680, height: 1050 });
const todays_date = new Date();
const createdPDF = path.join(__dirname, 'files', todays_date.getTime() + '.pdf');

 // get local Bootstrap.min.css stylesheet
await page.addStyleTag({
  path: 'bootstrapmin.css'
});
// get local Bootstrap.min.js script
await page.addScriptTag({
  path: 'bootstrap.min.js'
});


await page.waitFor(10000);

const pdf = await page.pdf({
  path: createdPDF,
  format: "A4",
  printBackground: true,
  displayHeaderFooter: true,
  headerTemplate: `<div style="font-size:7px;white-space:nowrap;margin-left:38px;">
                      ${new Date().toDateString()}
                      <span style="margin-left: 10px;">Lesson Notes</span>
                  </div>`,
  footerTemplate: `<div style="font-size:7px;white-space:nowrap;margin-left:38px;width:100%;">
                      Lesson Notes
                      <span style="display:inline-block;float:right;margin-right:10px;">
                          <span class="pageNumber"></span> / <span class="totalPages"></span>
                      </span>
                  </div>`,
  margin: {
    top: '38px',
    right: '38px',
    bottom: '38px',
    left: '38px'
  }
});
await browser.close();
res.set({
  "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
  "Content-Length": pdf.length
});
res.sendFile(createdPDF);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
console.log('server started on port 5000. Press Ctrl+C to quit');
});
```

However, I want to use index.php instead of index.html. But replacing index.html with index.php in the public folder fails to generate the pdf.

My requirement:

How do I setup the above node server.js code to use index.php instead of the default index.html?

Comment: You... don't? Expressjs is a webserver framework for Node.js, which is a Javascript standard library, executed by the V8 Javascript engine. If you ask it to serve a .php file --a _completely different_ programming language and engine-- it will literally purely do that: it will send the file itself, as plain data. It won't _run_ it, because Node.js is not not PHP

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, ok. Which options are left for me to go about this issue.

Comment: @kibikawanjala switch to a server that processes PHP.

Comment: @Phix, specifically I am biased towards Node.js because I am generating pdf using puppeteer which works well on Node.js, unless you have a server in mind that processes PHP - I will be glad to hear about it.

Comment: options you have: (1) redo your PHP code using Node.js/Express. Probably what I'd tell you to do if you paid me as a consultant, after (2) setting up a secondary PHP server that _temporarily_ runs at the same time as your node server, that your node server and be a proxy for, so you can set up some Express routes that simply respond "whatever the PHP server responds" but with that php server only being exposed locally. There's option (3) which is "try desperately to make Node.js "do PHP" including trying to `exec` the PHP interpreter and catching its stdio/err" but that's just ridiculous

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans; is it possible to discuss the possibility of helping me get this done.

Comment: no: _why would you rename it_? HTML webpages use .html, PHP files use .php. If it's not a PHP file, which it isn't, don't give it a `.php` extension. Done? You don't _need_ an `index.php` in the slightest, because you're not using PHP.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, you had suggested you can step in and get this done. Are you available.

Comment: I most certainly didn't, I told you what I'd tell you to do if you paid me as a consultant, not as a contractor to do the work for you. If you still have this problem, I would strongly advise you that, given that it's several months later, you close this post, and open a new question that properly details your current setup (because from your post alone, you say you have an index.html, so there is no reason to rename it. Maybe you also have a secondary php server running, but you don't talk about that: talk about that in your post)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, spot on! Exactly, I have a secondary PHP server running. I will post the question with full details latest on Monday next week. Thank you for helping figure out my problem description.